# Dual monitor set-up and wallpaper not expanding [Ubuntu Gnome]

Tags: gnome, nvidia, multiple-monitors, desktop-background

Recently I installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 and here's my problem.

After installing Ubuntu Gnome I wanted to set a wallpaper (3840x2160) for my dual monitor set-up (3840x1080). The problem is that the wallpaper isn't expanding to both of my screens and after a lot of research I still haven't found an answer to why it isn't spanning.

I tried :

- Changing to Wallpaper in the Tweak Tool pannel
- Installing Nitrogen (that doesn't work for me at all)

And that's pretty  much it.

What's even weirder is the fact that when I go to activities (top left corner) or Show Application, the Wallpaper is correctly set in the background.

I'm running an Nvidia GTX780, and both of my monitors are connected to it via DVI

Thanks for your time.

(Side note, English isn't my native language so i'm sorry in advance for the mistakes that I've already made or will make.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I thought that by adding a wallpaper (3840x2160) that wasn't the exact same size as my dual monitor set-up (3840x1080), Ubuntu would have adjusted it, but it didn't.

So I search for 3840x1080 wallpapers, spanned it in the Tweak Tool panel and now it works. 
But still it confuses me that when I was in Activities or Show Application the wallpaper was perfectly set in the background.

Comment: One programmer did the right thing, the other not quite, so I would file a bug...  Good question, good answer, both upvoted and thank you for making this site a better place!  ;-)
(and don't forget to accept your answer in a few days)